# PHP variables not rendering in the right place

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, concatenation, buddypress

I have the following in PHP, using Wordpress + Buddypress addon:

```
$blogusers = get_users('role=s2member_level1&number=5');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
  $username = str_replace('"', '',$user->user_nicename);
  $fullname = str_replace('"', '',bp_profile_field_data( array( 'user_id'=>$user->ID,'field'=>'name' ) ));
  $category = str_replace('"', '',bp_profile_field_data( array( 'user_id'=>$user->ID, 'field'=>'category' ) ));
  echo '<div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px;">';
  echo '<h3><a href="members/' . $username . '">' . $fullname .  '</a></h3>';
  echo '<strong>Camp Type: </strong>' . $category . '<br />';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

The $fullname and $category vars get bumped to before the float:left element, but the a $username variable stays in place, which is how all the variables are supposed to be rendered.

ie:

```
<div class="page" id="blog-latest" role="main">
<div style="width:500px;height:100px;position:relative;">
Frank GoreType 4<div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px;"><h3><a href="members/fgore"></a></h3><strong>Camp Type: </strong><br /></div>
</div>
```

Any clue is to why those two variables are being tossed out of the echo statement?

Comment: Can you also give an output sting?

Comment: Or can you provide the current site link for display?

Comment: Sorry, updated with output string

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how php's echo construct deals with concatenations.  It makes absolutely no sense to me, but apparently, when a concatenation occurs, it opens up a temp variable to perform the combine and then outputs the result.

If you're going to use that syntax, replace the periods with commas in the echo statements.  Echo treats comma separated values as separate statements and echos them in the order they were received.

Plus, it's a teeny bit faster = but only on the order of 1 second per millions of echo statements. :)

My preferred method is to create an html string and then echo once per logical block.

```
$echo = '<div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px;">'
      . '<h3><a href="members/' . $username . '">' . $fullname .  '</a></h3>'
      . '<strong>Camp Type: </strong>' . $category . '<br />'
      . '</div>';
echo $echo;
```

Comment: I tried both ways - echoing a string with commas instead of periods, and storing the html into $echo before echoing the result - and both ways returned the same result. The difference is, when using $echo, double quotes are added at the beginning and end of the output.

Comment: Ah, I was just going to comment that it then seems likely that the profile_field_data function wasn't returning a static string, but it looks like you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it has something to do with bp_profile_field_data. It is a function used by the core to retrieve data. The more developer-friendly method, get_bp_profile_field_data, was much better to work with. I'm getting proper formatting of all my strings. I appreciate you sharing the knowledge, however. Thanks!